# What hose bib to use?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I need to replace this hose bib. The guy at HD said I need a 1/2 inch hose bib with a female end.

[image]

I think I need one that needs to be sweated in, not female.  I say that because the adapter it connects to, it is perfectly round.  The 3/4 -> 1/2 inch male adapters I saw were not round on the outside, they had similar wrench-grip (six sided) like the hose bib has.

Who is correct?

If I am correct, I think I'm going to remove the adapter itself and replace with a 3/4->1/2 inch male adapter, and buy a 1/2" hose bib with female end.

Does this sound right?

Comment: it's hard to see from this angle. there's a hexagonal part at the back with a possible tool mark, it could be screwed on.

Comment: Is your supply line coming vertically out of the ground?

Comment: If you plan to change parts anyway, I'd suggest a FPT adapter since MPT hose bibbs / boiler drains are common as dirt (and most are also dual purpose - solderable on the inside), while FPT ones are unusual. Without a closer view I can't tell for sure if this bibb is soldered on or threaded in, but the hex would be unusual on a solder bibb unless it was dual-purpose, and then you would see the threads if it was soldered. I'd bet on a round exterior 3/4 sweat to 1/2 FPT adapter and MPT on the bibb, but it would not be a large bet without a closer look.

Comment: @jimstewart yes supply lines comes out of ground vertically.  Shutoff valve is right below the hose bib.

Comment: I have that same setup but without the added fittings and without the shutoff (a very useful feature). Originally a hydrant was simply sweated onto the vertical copper line. Mine was 1/2" but yours appears to be 3/4". When I replaced the hydrant in 1980 I sweated on a brass transition fitting (1/2" copper to 1/2" FIP)  and screwed in a right angle valve with 1/2" MIP threads. Might have been better to sweat on a male transition. Three years ago when I had to replace that one it was wrenches only.  Of course sometimes it is a challenge to achieve a leak free threaded connection.

Comment: But since you have the right angle from an ell fitting I think you should keep it and put any threaded transition after the ell in the horizontal. This gives a wider choice of hose bibs.

Comment: Since you have a convenient shutoff valve you could remove the stem and take it to a plumbing supply and get a replacement. You could examine the valve seat and replace that if it is replaceable. In short do you really need a whole new valve?

Comment: do what i do: buy all the parts to do the job both ways, then return what you don't end up using.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, here is a hose bib with hex that requires solder, i don't know what a dual-purpose one would look like.  https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-x-3-4-in-Brass-SWT-x-MHT-No-Kink-Hose-Bibb-VHNSTDA3EB/205817695

Comment: @greg that is the same one I use works on both 1/2 & 3/4 copper. I guess I should mention I pull the valve apart when sweating them on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would repair the valve assembly less than a dollar for the seat and some valve packing.

If you want to replace it it is a sweated fitting standard 1/2 nipple goes on the inside of the fitting for 1/2” and 3/4 goes on the outside of the fitting or that is the style I purchase under 10$

Edit
I looked up the style I use 1/2”. 3/4” brass SWT x mHT no kink hose bib $7.97 at home desperate.

Comment: thanks @edbeal, i didn't even think about that. I bought a replacement bibb of same brand but the turn handle doesn't fit the one above, but i didn't think about removing the whole part.  i will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed today.  It was a 1/2 - 3/4" Bibb that had to be sweated on.  The Bibb itself I am sure is 20+ years old, I could not find a replacement handle nor a replacement top piece, I ordered the same manufacturer bibb but neither part worked.  Appreciate everyone's help!